# Getting TF201006 when uploading process template

Tags: tfs

I added a link-type with Forward=Task and Reverse=User Story using a Dependency. I uploaded this to my collection successfully.

Now I delete the link type and upload the template successfully again.

When I now want to create a new link type containing "Task" as Forward I get the error:

> TF201006: The link type NEWNAME conflicts with link type OLDNAME. The name Task is already being used. (type ProvisionValidationException)

I don't see how to remove the OLDNAME.xml on my TFS because I don't know, where those uploaded templates are stored. Obviously the ProcessEditor will leave those files even if you remove a link type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The LinkTypes are uploaded as entries in the LinkTypes-table on the SQL-Server-Database responsible for the team collection you upload the template to. So if you experience the same problems go ahead and delete all items from this table which are added by yourself.